# How to access entity from relationship in ember-data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I have two entities User and Token. I fetched token using store.find(..) and then I would like to get it's user but its undefined.

```
// Route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
  needs:['session'],
  afterModel: function(token) {
    console.log(token); // defined, contains token
    console.log(token.get('user')); // undefined??
  },
  model: function (params) {
    return this.store.find('token', {token: params.token});
  },
  serialize: function (model, params) {
    return {token: model.get('token')};
  }
});

// user.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  tokens: DS.hasMany('token')
});

// token.js
export default DS.Model.extend({
  user: DS.belongsTo('user'),
});
```

When I check what data are loaded inside chrome ember inspector I can see token. When I click on `Belongs to` segment, there is `user : <computed>` and after another click the user is loaded. So how can I get token's user?

Comment: did you tried with token.get('user') in afterModel?

Comment: Yes, undefined as well. I am really confused I googled it for few hours and couldn't find any example of accessing relation except in template.

Comment: Did you check in model hook that 'params.token' property has id value?

Comment: Thanks, that was the issue. The goal is to load token not by id but by hash. Server accepts /token/{hash} but I cannot use it because ember then thinks that hash is id. So I solved this problem with ```find('token', {})``` but that will return Ember.Array and here lies the problem. Make it as answer, I'll accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you check in model hook that 'params.token' property has id value?